# How to render java.awt.Graphics2D in PdfDocument using iText7?

Tags: itext7

```
//writer is an instance of PdfWriter
PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate temp = contentByte.createTemplate(width ,height);
Graphics2D g2d = temp.createGraphics(width, height);
Rectangle2D r2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,width ,height);
//chart is an instance of JFreeChart and info is the information required for rendering a chart in JFreeChart
chart.draw(g2d,r2d,info);
img = Image.getInstance(temp);
document.add(img);
```

This is the code in iText 5. How to obtain the `Graphics2D` object using Itext7?

Comment: As it happens, I am planning on testing JFreeChart compatibility with iText 7 and writing a blog post about it for the iText blog. But that is not scheduled yet and I don't expect it to happen before July. If you can figure it out before I get around to doing it, then you're welcome to write a guest blog post. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue updating the version and this was the solution I ended up with:

```
document.add(convertChartToImage(chart));
```

Where convertChartToImage(...) is the following:

```
private Image convertChartToImage(JFreeChart chart) throws IOException {
    Image result = null;
    BufferedImage original = chart.createBufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        ImageIO.write(original, "png", os);
        os.flush();

        ImageData image = ImageDataFactory.create(os.toByteArray());

        result = new Image(image);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps. There might be a better way.